# ¿Cómo solucionar error en código de instabot con id de localización?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

[image: Función que intenta buscar la localización.]

[image: Error, Except on get media]

Al ejecutar el código se espera la identificación o la realización de ciertas acciones de acuerdo a las ubicaciones dadas con el id, al ejecutar esa parte del código siempre pasa y ejecuta el Except pero no las acciones que se esperan, alguna recomendación? Podrías ayudarme?

Comment: siempre es mejor añadir el código por medio del editor de texto

Comment: ¿Qué excepción es la que te imprime? Ten en cuenta que con `except Exception as e:` estás capturando _cualquier_ excepción que pudiera producirse, incluyendo el intento de acceder a una clave de diccionario no existente, que bien podría ser la causa en tu caso, o al intento de parsear como JSON algo que no lo es, que también podría ser.

Comment: @abulafia el error lo adjunté en otra imagen, donde aparece el número 2 puedes verla, y es el único momento donde falla el código, de resto funciona con normalidad.

Comment: @ShadowPaz es un código demasiado extenso, y como dije en el anterior comentario, todo el código (al parecer funciona con normalidad) menos esa acción. Espero tu respuesta.

Comment: Lo único que veo en la imagen que adjuntas es "Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)", pero no se ve el tipo de la excepción. Probablemente haya sido lanzada por `json.loads()` porque haya recibido una cadena que no tiene el formato esperado (no es json válido). Prueba a imprimir en el log, además del error de la excepción, el valor de `r.text` para encontrar qué está mal.